# Installed ios app opening issue on 16+ version

Tags: ios, xcode, ios16

Flutter Based ios app

1. I'm able to install the app through xcode and the app is working fine.
2. But when I kill the app and I try to open installed app it is not opening.

Issue is having with ios version 16+ device.
I'm checking on real device 16+ (tried on (16.5) ios version.

But it is working fine with above flow (1, 2) on ios version 13

anyone have any idea please comment.

Thanks for your support

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76482056/xcode14-3-unable-to-install-a-valid-provisioning-profile-for-this-executable